# Add firewall exception

Tags: vb.net, firewall, tcplistener, windows-firewall

I'm working on a server/client TCP communication and it works fine, altough I can't make an application to add the software to the Windows firewall exception. I did found a sample, but it didn't worked.

My code:

```
Imports NetFwTypeLib
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        Dim appType As Type = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("HnetCfg.FwAuthorizedApplication")
        Dim app As INetFwAuthorizedApplication
        app = DirectCast(Activator.CreateInstance(appType), INetFwAuthorizedApplication)

        ' Set the application properties
        app.Name = "My App"
        app.ProcessImageFileName = "c:\users\klein\documents\visual studio 2012\projects\tcp_server\tcp_server\bin\debug\tcp_server.exe"
        app.Enabled = True

        ' Get the firewall manager, so we can get the list of authorized apps
        Dim fwMgrType As Type = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("HnetCfg.FwMgr")
        Dim fwMgr As INetFwMgr
        fwMgr = DirectCast(Activator.CreateInstance(fwMgrType), INetFwMgr)

        ' Get the list of authorized applications from the Firewall Manager, so we can add our app to that list
        Dim apps As INetFwAuthorizedApplications
        apps = fwMgr.LocalPolicy.CurrentProfile.AuthorizedApplications
        apps.Add(app)
    End Sub
End Class
```

The code runs perfectly, no exception detected. Yet, the program is not listed after the form is loaded.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Look at this:

[Programatically Add Exceptions to a Windows Firewall Using C#](http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/.net/net_general/tipstricks/article.php/c14167/Programatically-Add-Exceptions-to-a-Windows-Firewall-Using-C.htm)

Comment: The instructions are for `SQLServer`, it would be better if you could provide code that shows OP how it works for server/client TCP.

Comment: Thank you, but I managed to make it work, the problem was that the program had to be ran as administrator.